# Contagem de caracteres em textarea AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estou precisando criar uma forma  de mostrar a **quantidade** de **caracteres restantes** em um **textearea** de cadastro de uma descrição para um determinado perfil.

Essa parte é a de inserção dos dados:

```
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" 
          name="description_validate" ng-model="group.description" 
          ng-minlength='{{valideDescricao.description_validate.minlength}}' 
          ng-maxlength="{{valideDescricao.description_validate.maxlength}}" 
          ng-required='valideDescricao.description_validate.required' />
```

Essa outra é a parte da minha visualização dos dados:

```
<td align="justify" style="width: 500px"  data-title="'Descrição'" filter="{description: 'text'}" >{{row.description}}</td>
```

Quero saber se existe alguma forma de fazer a operação com o Angular sem eu ter que fazer toda uma função em JavaScript, se existe alguma diretiva de fazer essa funcionalidade, ou uma forma padrão no *controller* e na *view*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe sim, no seu caso ficaria:

```
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" 
          name="description_validate" ng-model="group.description" 
          ng-minlength='{{valideDescricao.description_validate.minlength}}' 
          ng-maxlength="{{valideDescricao.description_validate.maxlength}}" 
          ng-required='valideDescricao.description_validate.required' />

<span>{{valideDescricao.description_validate.maxlength - group.description.length}} restantes</span>
```

*caso você esteja usando angularJS 1.1.1 ou uma versão mais recente é necessário adicionar `ng-trim="false"` no `textarea`, segue um exemplo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <textarea ng-model="txtarea" ng-trim="false" maxlength="200"></textarea>
    <span>{{200 - txtarea.length}} caracteres restantes</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Realmente muito simples e funcional, sem precisar criar toda uma função no controller e trazer para a view, todas as respostas que eu achava eram criando funções externas para uma coisa simples.

Answer (score 1):

Não há necessidade de componentes externos. Entretanto você precisa expandir o comportamento padrão de `ng-model`, já que ele não propaga as propriedades do elemento, `maxlength` entre elas:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('ngModel', function attributeNgModelDirective() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.attributes = attrs; //adiciona os atributos do elemento como uma
                               // propriedade do modelo
    }
  };
})
.controller('myController', function($scope){});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <form name="meuForm">
    <div ng-controller='myController'>
       <input name="entrada" id="entrada" ng-model="description" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="200" />
       <br/>
       <span>Caracteres restantes: {{meuForm.entrada.attributes.maxlength - meuForm.entrada.$viewValue.length}}</span>
       <pre>{{meuForm.entrada | json }}</pre>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Uma dúvida, porque ele não mostra "199" ? Ele pula direto do 200 pro 198

Comment: @ArturoTemplário Isso é por causa da presença do `ng-minlength`, que invalida o modelo se o valor tiver um comprimento menor do que 2.

Comment: muito obrigado, não entendo muito sobre AngularJS ainda

Comment: @ArturoTemplário sempre um prazer! Estamos todos aprendendo. =)

Comment: @OdoSendai Também reparei isso, ele pulou do 200 para o 198, no outro exemplo do Mathias ele mostra normalmente 200, 199, 198 ... eu não sabia que o ng-minlength invalidaria a escrita do número 199 na tela nesse caso

Comment: @PhilipRamkeerat é que o valor, sendo inválido (você pode notar pela flag `$valid: false`), não é propagado para o modelo pelo angular. Eu alterei a resposta para incluir um dump do objeto, onde você pode ver as flags. Note que `$viewValue` tem o valor correto, mas `$modelValue` é apenas preenchido se passar na validação.

Comment: @PhilipRamkeerat Eu alterei a resposta para que o cálculo ocorra contra o comprimento de $viewValue, preservando assim o comportamento esperado pelo usuário.